# How to install chrome in custom location using chocolatey

Tags: google-chrome, installation, chocolatey, choco

I want to install chrome in a custom location by using chocolatey, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I know I have to use

```
choco install googlechrome --installargs "<someargs>"
```

but I can not find the args to pass. Is this even possible?

I *don't* want to install chrome in the default directory

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application`

Comment: Chocolatey package doesn't have a install location set, and chrome doesn't allow you to install it in a custom location, so i don't think you'll be able to do such task.

Comment: @AhmadMM "chrome doesn't allow you to install it in a custom location" do you have an official source for this?